# Can I do my graduate studies in Computer Science with computational physcis bachelor degree?

Tags: graduate-admissions, computer-science, physics

I have graduated in computational physics with gpa 3.1. I need to do my graduate studies in computer science in USA or Europe.

Comment: Considering that my bachelor's degree is in physics (not computational) and my doctorate is in mathematics, I infer that a transition like yours should be possible. I would not, however, infer that it's possible from every university to every university.

Answer (score 1):

The best advise I can give you is to check what the prerequisites for graduate studies in computer science are. Check the homepages of the programs of different universities in the USA or Europe.

Some might require a degree in computer science or a related field, other just a certain amount of points related to computer science. 
To find out if a university considers computational physics as a related field you have to ask.

I am European, so I can't tell you if a GPA of 3.1 is good enough or how it affects your ability to get into a university in Europe.

You have to check and find out yourself. 
After graduating you should be able to do that.